# Compatibility issues with WordPress super cache and minify plugins

Tags: caching, minify, super

I'm having a big problem. I have WordPress super cache and I installed a plugin call minify. Add to use my back up, then I took off minify, but WordPress super cache is not caching now. It gave me this message:

```
Fetching http://mmolist.com/ to prime cache: OK

Fetching first copy of http://mmolist.com/: OK (1.html)

Fetching second copy of httpLINK ABOVE: OK (2.html)

The pages do not match! Timestamps differ or were not found!
```

I tried 775 and 777 in the folder, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, you can't use minify with WP Super Cache whatsoever. If you do, you will get that message. Even if you use a CDN and enable minify there you will continue to get that message. I was experiencing that issue as well and the minify in the CDN was my culprit so I had to disable it. Here is an article on how to do it https://www.msgdigital.com/wp-super-cache-tester-pages-not-match-fix/

Answer (score 0):

" The pages do not match! Timestamps differ or were not found!"

You get this error in WP super cache when you test page cache. Since you are using a minify plugin, do not enable the option to minify HTML. 
If you are using CDN service like Cloudflare see a [detail post on this link](https://tipsnfreeware.com/fixpages-do-not-matchtimestamps-differ-wp-super-cache/)

Hope this helps.